# Disable Specific SystemSettings.exe Win10

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to disable only specific segments of the SystemSettings.exe window in Windows 10, for example, I want to disable modifying/looking at the settings of the Multitasking tab of it. If there isn't a way to do this, is there a way to simply disable SystemSettings.exe **exclusively** and not using the group policy that also blocks Control Panel.

[image: Image for reference <https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1TUk4PvcJiFUjNKQngwSVIwLWs>]

EDIT: It seems there is an app version that runs from the start menu, if there is a way to block that, that would be helpful.

Comment: Your image does not work.  You should upload to `i.stack.imgur.com` instead.  Your question is also confusing.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of preventing access to these settings? Maybe that will help us find you an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

make prohibit-systemsettings.ps1 and set taskSchedular by grouppolicy

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_ProcessStartTrace -SourceIdentifier processStarted
while($true){
    $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier processStarted
    $x = Get-Process -Name SystemSettings -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if(!$x -eq $false){$x.Kill()}
    Remove-Event processStarted
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To disable access to SystemSettings.exe only. In admin mode go to c: \ windows \ immersiveControlPanel \ and property, security of SystemSettings.exe. Edit authorization of your user account to all denied, before resuming the rights Trusteinstaller to administrator.restart system login to user and go to pc parameter to test this now no access is possible, but in administrator mode it is accesible.
Eric

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of writing a good answer is providing context for the proposed solution. Please edit your answer and explain why your solution works, and what, *specifically*, it does.